# PDO, How to get subset rows not all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have a question:

How to fetch subset from result statement in PDO ? I know fetchAll get all result but I just want get subset with range index so that make memory more efficient.

can anyone help me about my question..

thanks,

Comment: You need to show the query you are referring to and what you mean by "subset".

Answer (score 0):

PDO has nothing to do with subsets.
You have to SELECT already a subset, using LIMIT clause, and than fetch i using whatever API you're using.